# What benzodiazepine least causes physical dependence?

Tags: drug-tolerance, benzodiazepines

Benzodiazepines are drugs that [cause physical dependence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_dependence), so much that there is a [movement critical to using them](https://www.benzoinfo.com/paradoxical-reactions/#:%7E:text=A%20paradoxical%20reaction%20happens%20when,relief%20medication%20causing%20increased%20pain.).

Some benzodiazepines have been labled "short term" such as [brotizolam](https://go.drugbank.com/drugs/DB09017), [triazolam](https://www.drugs.com/mtm/triazolam.html), [midazolam](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Midazolam&oldid=1160930299#Pharmacology) and even clonazepam which I understand to have [a longer half life of all three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clonazepam).
I never found "long term" benzodiazepines so I assume non are existing.
But instead of talking about short term or long term I personally talk about intervals, such as:

- Each day up to one month, or as instructed by a physician
- [Once a week](https://www.healthline.com/health/anxiety/withdraw-from-benzodiazepines#:%7E:text=If%20you%20take%20benzodiazepines%20infrequently,risk%20of%20dependence%20or%20withdrawal.) up to one year, espeically alongside other psychotropic drug/s as part of a [synergic treatment](https://www.biologyonline.com/dictionary/synergistic-effect), aimed at lowering physical dependence chance, or as instructed by a physician

But regardless of interval, what benzodiazepine least causes physical dependence?